# Count words program reading whole file as one word

Tags: c++, while-loop, eof, word-count

*Beginner to C++ and programming here*

I want to write a program which counts the number of words in a file.
I am testing it with only one file, but it should work for other files with different formatting ie. multiple spaces. (I am assuming that there are no issues with the file opening etc for now)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> // these are the only imports I can use
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("story.txt"); // open the file called filename

void skip_space(char c) {
    cout << "skip_space()\n";

    while (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') { // as long as char is space
        c = fin.get(); // get next character from file

        if (fin.eof()) { // if eof is raised
            return;
        }
    } // while
    return;
}

void skip_char(char c) {
    cout << "skip_char()\n";

    while (c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t') { // as long as char is not space
        c = fin.get(); // get next character from file

        if (fin.eof()) { // if eof is raised
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}


void num_words() { 
    cout << "num_words()\n";
    int word_count = 0;
    char c = fin.get(); // get first character of file

    while (!fin.eof()) { // while not end of file

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            skip_space(c); // loops until an nonblank character is reached
        } else { // if not a blank
            word_count++; // increment count
            skip_char(c); // loops until a space is reached
        }
    }

    cout << "story.txt" << " has " << word_count << " words\n";
    // prints a message to cout indicating the number of words in filename. 
    // A word is defined as the string that an input stream (such as cin) returns when reading a string value.
}

int main() {
    num_words();
}
```

Here are the contents of the file:

```
One day
a green
a frog ate a 
princess.
```

When I run the code the output is

```
num_words()
skip_char()
story.txt has 1 words
```

The problem is the word_count is 1 instead of 9. I am very confused in general. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `(c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t')` should be `(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')`

Comment: Three is not four. Four is not three. Every other number is both not three and not four. Thus every number is not three or not four.

Comment: oohhh how did I not see that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you write `while (c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t')`, then this condition will always be met, regardless of the value of `c` (because for any `c`, it is for sure either different from `' '` OR different from `'\n'`).

You probably meant `while (! (c==' ' || c !== '\n' || c == '\t')) { ...`.

Note further, that - as you tagged the question with C++, you could use `cin >> aString`, which automatically skips any white spaces, and simply count how often this operations succeeds.

Comment: Man, I was making it so much more complicated than it needed to be. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have a small logic flow in your program. The problem is within your skip_char function.
Look at this line:

```
while (c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t')
```

Think what will happen in case you a read space character for example. The condition should be:

```
 while (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
```

I strongly suggest to understand why your condition is wrong, and also learn how to find such bugs by yourself, for instance think what kind of printing you could add for your code in order to find this bug. Another option is to try familiarize yourself with a debugger that work in the system you work in.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start using on from now on :)